# Error al momento de insertar datos en SQL y al enviar correo con php

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**Quiero enviar los datos de un formulario por correo y en la base de datos al mismo tiempo, pero lo envio por correo y al momento de hacer la conexión con la bd y hacer el post no jala.**

Aquí esta mi código :

```php
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "tickett";
$username = "Jod";
$password = "23451";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);f (!$conn) {
     die("Con failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$boletos = $_POST['boletos'];
$com = $_POST['com'];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (`Id` ,`Nombre` , `Telefono` , `Correo` , `Cantidad` , `Comentario`) 
VALUES ("' . $name . '", "' . $tel . '", "' . $mail. '", "' . $boletos. '", "' . $com. '")';
mysqli_close($conn);


namespace ContactForm;
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);
   if($responseData->success) {
       $email = 'test@gmail.com';
       $message = '';
       foreach($_POST as $label => $value) {
           if( $label != 'g-recaptcha-response' ) {
               $label = ucwords($label);
               if( is_array($value) ) {
                   $value = implode(', ', $value);
               }
               $message .= $label.": " . htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
           }
       }
       $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
       try {
           $mail->SMTPDebug = $debug;                               
           $mail->AddAddress($email);                                
           $mail->IsHTML(true); 
           $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
           $mail->Subject = $subject;
           $mail->Body    = $message;
           $mail->Send();
           $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error','errorMessage'=>$e->errorMessage());
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error','errorMessage'=>$e->getMessage());
       }
?>
```

Y al momento de hacer la conexión con la BD y el post me sale la página en blanco, quiero enviar el correo y hace el pos en la bd al mismo tiempo.
No se si alguien me puede apoyar a resolver[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar la definición de la tabla en la que estás intentando insertar los datos? Tengo la impresión que el error podría ser por los datos que estas intentando insertar.

Comment: Creo que sobra un `catch`. Esto es correcto? `INSERT INTO table` la tabla se llama `table`?

Comment: Si @EduardPinuaga asi se llama

Comment: Es que como en el error muestra el nombre de la tabla como `Boletos`

Comment: Le habia puesto boletos, pero lo cambie, y el error no esta ahi.

Comment: @danielpmsv ya lo agregue, en la publicacion principal

Comment: El id debería ser `Id_Boletos` o almenos en `$sql` no coincide.

Comment: Ya, lo cambie y sigue igual.

Comment: Pon la estructura exacta de los archivos ya que , por ejemplo `namespace ContactForm;`  deberia ir al principio del archivo. Hay un 'if' sin la *i* me imagino que será al crear la pregunta pero mira de editar la pregunta con sus valores correctos, así como el nombre de la tabla del INSERT, que coincida con la estructura de la Tabla ya que sino la gente estará dando vueltas en esos puntos. Y sera más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

por lo que pude ver la asignación de las variables están bien, incluso llega la información, a mi parecer pueden ser las comillas dobles, intenta lo siguiente:

```
"INSERT INTO table (`Id` ,`Nombre` , `Telefono` , `Correo` , `Cantidad` , `Comentario`) 
VALUES ('. $name .', '. $tel .', '. $mail. ', '. $boletos. ', '. $com.')";`
```

O prueba también:

```
"INSERT INTO table (`Id` ,`Nombre` , `Telefono` , `Correo` , `Cantidad` , `Comentario`) 
VALUES ('$name', '$tel', '$mail', '$boletos','$com')";`
```

De ser posible, evita dejar los espacios, prueba las dos formas y nos comentas.

Comment: Los campos que de tipo `varchar` necesitará comillas dobles en los values.

Comment: No necesariamente

Comment: Creo que el problema no esta ahi, porque si me dda los datos

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no es necesario el campo 'Id', monta la query sin el ID...

```
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO table (`Nombre` , `Telefono` , `Correo` , `Cantidad` , `Comentario`) 
VALUES ("' . $name . '", "' . $tel . '", "' . $mail. '", "' . $boletos. '", "' . $com. '")';
```

> Al insertar esta esperando el campo del *id* y este es ya se
>   autocompleta en la BBDD y no cuadran los nombres de campos con los
>   values.

Un ejemplo con un INSERT con el id...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: {"response":"success"}Error: INSERT INTO table (`Nombre` , `Telefono` , `Correo` , `Cantidad`) VALUES ("Prueba_1", "7223772269", "mail@gmail.com", "1") @Eduard Pinuaga,

Comment: Cuándo ejecutas la query?

Comment: Asi es, es es lo que me salio.

Comment: Sí, pero cuándo ejecutas la Query? enq ue parte del código? de todas formas cuando yo ejecuto un INSERT con el id (si es autocompletado) me salta error. La ejecutaste sin el id?

Comment: Lo ejecute sin, porque se autocompletado

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta ya que en el código sale que lo ejecutas con el ID. Como te comente antes si la pregunta no refleja fielmente lo que haces difícilmente te podremos ayudar.